# Width of popup menus

Tags: menu, popup, codenameone

My simple pop-up menus are all coming up sized to narrow, so 
the longest elements are truncated by a character or two.  This
is consistent, no matter what the length of the longest element.
The list elements are all simple strings, so this seems like it must
be a bug, perhaps a bug in the default style guide that forgets to take
account of the borders.

Anyway, I've papered over the problem by subclassing DefaultLookAndFeel
and adding a fudge factor

```
public Dimension getListPreferredSize(List l)
{
    Dimension dim = super.getListPreferredSize(l);
    dim.setWidth(dim.getWidth()+20);
    return(dim);
}
```

Is this a reasonable approach?  Or else what should I do to get
menus to size properly.

Comment: It was a bug that was already been fixed, update your local libs.

Comment: I used the "refresh libs" action in eclipse, but it has no apparent effect.  Note that the list items are not literal strings, but objects that must be rendered by the internals calling toString() somewhere down the line.

Answer (score 0):

As @chen-fishbein mentioned this is a bug that was fixed.